# Can I use the switch statement in Livewire3 to switch the display of the entire screen?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

```
<div>
    @switch($mode)
        @case('login')
            <livewire:login />
            @break
        @case('menu')
            <livewire:menu />
            @break
        @default
            <livewire:menu />
    @endswitch
</div>
```

Of course I know "redirect" in Laravel.

I don't know if this source code is strictly correct. But if you read it, you will know what I want to do.

parent.php

```
#[On('mode-change')] 
public function mode($mode){
  $this->mode = $mode;
}
```

child.php

```
public function goMenu() {
  $this->dispatch('mode-change', mode: 'menu');
}
```

Comment: yes this could work, did you try it out?

Comment: @JasperHelmich Actually, yes I did try it. But that works were very slow! :) It's possible my source code wasn't good, so I'm just trying to get other's opinions in here.

Comment: Uhm i dont want to be that guy on stack overflow but why not use routing? Route per component and with wire:navigate on your a tags it still feels snappy!